# AttributeError at /admin 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-views, django-admin

I've deployed my Django project on Heroku. Now when I'm trying to access the admin page `url/admin`, I'm getting

> AttributeError at /admin
>
> 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'

If I'm running the same code locally, there's no issue with the admin page. It opens fine.

So problem is with this line actually in views.py

```
/app/exam/views.py in topic_view

    Line:59 |   fname = request.user.first_name
```

So my problem is why views.py is being called when I'm trying to open the admin site.

edit:

This is the urls.py file for app 'exam'

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("search", views.search_view, name="search"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register_view, name="register"),
    path("<str:subject_code>", views.topic_view, name="topics"),
    path("instructions/<int:topic_id>", views.instruction_view, name="instructions"),
    path("test/<int:topic_id>", views.test_view, name="test"),
    path("test/score/<int:topic_id>", views.score_calculator, name="score"),
    
]
```

and this is the urls.py for project 'quiz'

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("exam.urls")),
]
```

Comment: add your urls in your post.

Comment: Could you please show your url file?

Comment: You aren't checking that user is actually logged in. You can check if user is annonimous using this `request.user.is_anonymous`. Also, it's better to put a `@login_required` decorator, if your view is FBV.

Comment: I've added the urls.py @NalinDobhal

Comment: I've added the url file @Dmitry .

Comment: But why do I need to check that user is logged or not while opening the admin site @Charnel

Comment: try to comment this url `path("<str:subject_code>", views.topic_view, name="topics"),` and check if you can access admin.

Comment: @DarshilThakore `<str:subject_code>` is capturing your admin rout. You should change the path.

Comment: See, when I run the project locally on my pc, then everything works fine with the same code. But the deployed version is showing this error. Anyhow I'm trying your suggestion on the deployed code @NalinDobhal

Comment: You can try change route `path("<str:subject_code>", views.topic_view, name="topics"),`  to  `path("topic/<str:subject_code>", views.topic_view, name="topics"),`

Comment: I'm trying to make those suggested changes and I'll inform you of the results @Charnel

Comment: I'm trying to make those suggested changes and I'll inform you of the results @Dmitry

Comment: Hey @Dmitry, thanks for the suggestion, it worked and solved the issue. Still just out of curiosity, what are your views on why the same was working on local machine.

Comment: Hey @NalinDobhal  thanks for the suggestion, it worked and solved the issue. Still just out of curiosity, what are your views on why the same was working on local machine.

Comment: I am clueless here, that shouldn't have happened as 'admin' is the first url in the url configuration and from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request): `Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got AnonymousUser error, that means that the user is not logged in, and since he's/she's not logged in, he/she can't have any attribute like username, first_name etc.